# Binding mouse events to dynamically created select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have created select tag dynamically in jquery function. I want to bind the mouse events to it.
I have dynamically created the selct tag

```
function loadValues()
{
var sel='<select id="flavor_slct'+index+'" class="popper" data-popbox="pop1"     

onclick="alert()">'+flavor_fetched_string+'</select>';
$("#attach").append(sel);

}
```

I have tried using the `.on()` jQuery function. Still events are not triggered.

```
$("body").on("hover","Select",function()
    alert("hovered");
)};
```

How should i bind events to dynamically created elements.?

Comment: Syntax Error in `on()`. Should be `$("body").on("hover", "Select", function () {
    alert("hovered");
});`

Answer (score 1):

There is no `hover` JavaScript event triggered. You are probably looking for `mouseenter`.

You also have some incorrect syntax defining your function that I've rectified:

```
$("body").on("mouseenter", "select", function(){
    alert("hovered");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use bind or on.

```
$("document").on("mouseenter", "#flavor_slct", function(
)};
```

OR

```
$("document").bind("mouseenter", "#flavor_slct", function(
)};
```